# Firebird .NET Provider 3.0.2 slow performance over LAN

Tags: .net, performance, firebird

Thank you for your time beforehand :)

I'm in process of migrating my program WPF, .NET 4.0, SqlServer 2005 Express to Firebird.

Firebird is 2.5.2 security update 1 x64, Classic Server on Win 7 x64, Core i5, 4GB RAM.

in my program i'm fetching 500K rows with .net firebird provider (3.0.2.0) .NET 4.0:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable
```

There is no blob (text or binary) data. Same query runs on SqlServer 2005 in 15 seconds but with Firebird 2 minutes 27 seconds (on localhost). It's not a problem I can live with that. The real problem is that same query over network (100 MBit) takes 36 MINUTES to complete.
FlameRobin with Grid->Fetch all records runs this query in 7 seconds (on localhost).

Can you please help me identify problem(s)?

1. resmon shows no excessive write/read or extraordinary network activity
2. Increasing cache (RAM) didn't give different result

I just can't grab source of problem, any help guys?

Comment: What kind of times do you see if you use FlameRobin from a different host?

Comment: Sorry guys for inconvenience. There actually was text blob :( . I was fooled by FluentNHibernate mapping where there was no .Lenght(int.MaxValue) . Problem was in network performance when fetching/writing blob fields.

Comment: I think you should edit the question to add your clarification instead of just comment on it.

Comment: Any comment as how to improve this if there is a blob??

Comment: There is no way to improve this if you are using Firebird 2.x. Since I asked this question I switched to Couchdb + SQLite combination. But as far as I know there are great improvements in Firebird 3.x.